# ajax call not working with dual data parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

here's my ajax code below

```
$('.username-check').on('click', function() {
    //console.log('You clicked');
    alert(username);
    var username = $('.username-target'),
        lastname = $('.lastname-target'),
        feedback = $('.username-feedback');

    function changeFeednackText(text){ feedback.text(text); }

    function couldNotCheck(){ changeFeednackText('Could not check at this time'); }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'check/username.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            username: username.val(),
            lastname: lastname.val()
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.available !== undefined){
                if(data.available === true){
                    changeFeednackText('That username is available.');
                }else{
                    changeFeednackText('Sorry, that username is not available.');
                }
            }else{
                couldNotCheck();
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            couldNotCheck();
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML code

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <div>
        <label for="username">First Name<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="username-target"></label><br />
        <label for="lastname">Last Name<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="lastname-target"></label><br />
        <a href="javascript:;" class="username-check">Check username</a>
    </div>
    <div class="username-feedback"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Check"></div>
</form>
```

My PHP is also below

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$username = (isset($_GET['username'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']) : null;
$lastname = (isset($_GET['lastname'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['lastname']) : null;

$available = true;
if($username == 'bar' && $lastname == 'foo'){
// if($username == 'bar'){
    $available = false;
}
$arr = array('username' => $username . $lastname, 'available' => $available);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The above code works fine and returned `false` if I use if statement like this `if($username == 'bar'){` but when i use to check against two values such as `if($username == 'bar' && $lastname == 'foo'){` it always return `true`.

Please note that I've tried foo and bar as `username` and `lastname` respectively to get a `false` call back but no success. Don't know what is wrong here but I hope anyone of you could spot the error and help me out.. do you have any idea?

Comment: did you get a chance to check what data is being sent to your php via that ajax call , using firebug or something?

Comment: oh thanks @Satya ... no checked it now but its only sends username... but this is my first ever attempt to work with ajax so if you could see any issue please do let me know.

Comment: _... that I've tried foo and bar as username and lastname ..._ - shouldn't that be foo as lastname and bar as username? Otherwise, `true`is true.

Comment: how do i send two parameters through ajax

Comment: @Amjad - your code to send the two params looks proper. As well the PHP

Comment: Yes @AxelAmthor it works fine if i use `http://localhost/highcharts/check/username.php?username=amjad&lastname=khan` but my issue is send those value through ajax

Comment: A quick test shows it sending both the values just fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/rhzqwfbc/**, the PHP looks fine as well.

Comment: In your OP you wrote _... that I've tried foo and bar as username and lastname ..._ - shouldn't that be *foo as lastname* and *bar as username*? Otherwise, the output of `true`is proper - and true.

Comment: not its not @adeneo i tried it is saying `Could not check at this time`

Comment: That's because there is no server to respond, you have to look in the console and see that the querystring contains both values etc.

Comment: @AxelAmthor that is just a typing mistake I've tried that million times with the right order of the values

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
 if(data.available !== undefined){
```

to

```
 if( typeof(data.available) != "undefined" ) {
```

in your succes function.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Axel Amthor

Comment: It's no huge deal really, but you should always use strict equality comparisons in javascript... always.

Comment: @RyanWheale - only if you actually want to compare strict, for typeof it's not an issue, as it always returns a string... always, I'd be more concerned with typeof not being a function.